# Which one is more correct for academic writing? List of X users vs X-user list

Tags: academic-writing

I am writing an academic paper and having hard time with language.

So which one of the following is most appropriate?

1. List of WhatsApp users
2. WhatsApp-users list
3. WhatsApp user list
4. WhatsApp users' list
5. WhatsApp users list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your example is:

> Facebook explains their methodology: whoever has accessed the application on at least 30 different days is put on the _______

... then #1, "... list of WhatsApp users" is simple and direct.

Putting "list" after its modifier has the effect of "naming" the list. Of course, if the implication is that Facebook actually refers to the list by a proper noun, like "WhatsApp User List," then you would use that. I don't think that's your intention, but let's examine the remaining options.

#2 is hyphenated. The motivation for this might be that "list" is being modified by two words. But it's not necessary, because "WhatsApp" modifies "users." If it were the "needs-work list," a hyphen could be appropriate because a two-word phrase is being used as a single adjective.

#3 and 5 are different only in using singular vs plural. Strangely, both are valid options. We talk of a "guest list" for a party, not a "guests list." But note, the construction "list of users" has to use the plural.

#4 just got possessives confused with plurals. Bless its sweet heart. The only dimension in which it makes any sense is one in which all WhatsApp users collectively have joint custody of a single list.

Comment: Thank you. so looks like #1 is best right?

Comment: That becomes subjective. There’s nothing *wrong* with 3 and 5 per se. Personally, I find one to be clearest and to flow well.